# Dynamically change activeTintColor

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a React Native app, and I want to update the color of the `activeTintColor` on my tab bar based on an API value.

I know that in my `Component`, I can call:

```
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'red'
    },
  }
```

to change the color, *however*, within my tab navigator, I'm displaying a stack navigator, so if I add the above code in my component, it doesn't change the color.

Here's my router code (note that I am using a stack in my tabs, and that's what is causing the problem):

```
export const SpaceStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MainScreen: {
      screen: MainScreen,
    },
    AlertListScreen: {
      screen: AlertListScreen
    },
    ChartScreen: {
      screen: ChartScreen
    },
    ImpersonationScreen: {
      screen: ImpersonationScreen
    },
    SelectOrganizationScreen: {
      screen: SelectOrganizationScreen
    }
  }
);

export const SignedIn = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Space: {
      screen: SpaceStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Spaces',
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => (
          focused ? <Image
            style={{ tintColor: global.brandColor }}
             source={require('../images/icon_space_selected.png')}
           /> :
           <Image
              source={require('../images/icon_space.png')}
            />
        ),
      }
    },
    Alerts: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
            Alerts: {
                screen: AlertListScreen
            }
        }),
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Alerts',
            tabBarLabel: 'Alerts',
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => (
                  focused ? <Image
                   style={{ tintColor: global.brandColor }}
                   source={require('../images/icon_alerts_selected.png')}
                   /> :
                   <Image
                      source={require('../images/icon_alerts.png')}
                    />
                ),
        }
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => (
          focused ? <Image
            style={{ tintColor: global.brandColor }}
            source={require('../images/icon_settings_selected.png')}
           /> :
           <Image
              source={require('../images/icon_settings.png')}
            />
        ),
      }
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: global.brandColor,
      labelStyle: { fontFamily: FontMedium, },
    }
  }
);
```

Anyone know how I can change this?

Comment: If you use redux u can do it very easily!

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
//Some.js

import {connect} from 'react-redux';     

let renderTabs = ({tintColor})=>{
return createBottomTabNavigator({//route configs},{tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: tintColor,
  labelStyle: { fontFamily: FontMedium, },
}}
export default  connect(null,renderTabs);
```

Then you can dispatch an action to change your `tintColor`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `them` in react-naviagation

Colors that are specified within the static configuration options for a navigator can now be specified as objects with light and dark keys:

**Example**

```js
const ThemeContext = React.createContext(null);
const ThemeConstants = {
  light: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    fontColor: '#000',
  },
  dark: {
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    fontColor: '#fff',
  },
};

let Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    /* routes */
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: ThemeConstants[theme].activeTintColor,
      inactiveTintColor: ThemeConstants[theme].inactiveTintColor,
    },
  }
);
```

See [more information](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/themes.html)